# Synchronization code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, synchronization

I have the following code to execute below, the problem is that all the images ok appears at the same time after executing the program.

I want what appears it article by article. Image by image. Each time an article is executed, the program displays the image ok and passes the execution of the following article:

```js
// autocomplet : this function will be executed every time we change the text
function autocomplet() {
    var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#country_id').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_refresh.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#country_list_id').show();
                $('#country_list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#country_list_id').hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item) {
    // change input value
    $('#country_id').val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#country_list_id').hide();
}
```

```css
fieldset{
width:200px;
}

#periode{
width:200px;
float:left;
margin-right:120px;
}

#article{
    padding-top: 36px;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#valider{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#tableau1{
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

#table1{
font-size:12px;
}

#recalculer,#suivant,#valoriser{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#clear {
  clear: both;
  }
#corps ,#entete,#pied{
text-align:center;
  margin:auto;
  width:1200px;
  background-color:white;
  }

#pied{
    background-image:linear-gradient(white,#006BB6);
    line-height: 120px;
    height:80px;
}

#corps{
min-height:500px;
  }
#entete .left{
    float:left;
}
#entete{
    height:120px;
}
#entete .right{
    float:right;
}

body{
  background-image:linear-gradient(#006BB6,white);
  }

#table,#table1{
    margin:auto;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 97%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}

#table th,#table1 th {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #006BB6;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #006BB6;
    padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
}
#table CAPTION,#table1 CAPTION {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #EC131C;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #006BB6;
    padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
}
.copyright{
display:block;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
#table td,#table1 td{
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #006BB6;
    padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
    text-align:center;
}
#table tr:hover td,#table1 tr:hover td{
    background-color:#58FA58;
}
#table1 td{
 font-size: 14px;
}

.button {
   border-top: 1px solid #455402;
   background: #004285;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#006BB6), to(#004285));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #006BB6, #004285);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #006BB6, #004285);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #006BB6, #004285);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #006BB6, #004285);
   padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: Georgia, serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
.button:hover {
   border-top-color: #475702;
   background: #475702;
   color: #ccc;
   }
.button:active {
   border-top-color: #364202;
   background: #364202;
   }

     .modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .modalDialog:target {
        opacity:1;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .modalDialog > div {
        width: 1200px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 5% auto;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    }

    .close {
        background: #606061;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        line-height: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -12px;
        text-align: center;
        top: -10px;
        width: 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-border-radius: 12px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    }

    .close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <Title>Revalorisation des coùts</Title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.json.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#recalculer').on('click', function() {
                var societe=$("#societe p").text();
                var arrayLignes = document.getElementById("table1").rows; //l'array est stocké dans une variable
                var longueur = arrayLignes.length;//on peut donc appliquer la propriété length
                var i=0; //on définit un incrémenteur qui représentera la clé

                while(i<longueur)
                {
                    article = arrayLignes[i].cells[0].textContent;
                    autorisation= arrayLignes[i].cells[7].textContent;
                    if (autorisation=="Oui") {
                        var retour="";
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "sleep.php",
                            async: false,
                            beforeSend: function(){
                                arrayLignes[i].cells[8].innerHTML = "<img height='60' src='images/ajax-loader.gif' />";
                                alert("avant valorisation "+ article);
                            },
                            success: function(msg){
                                    arrayLignes[i].cells[8].innerHTML = "<a href='"+msg+"' target='_blank'><IMG height='60' src='images/ok.png' alt='Voire rapport'></a>";
                                    alert("apres valorisation "+ article);
                                }
                            });
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                    document.getElementById("recalculer").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("maj").style.display = "inline";
                });
            $('#maj').on('click', function() {
                document.location.reload(true);
            });
            });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="entete">
        <img class='left' src='images/logo.png'/>
        <img class='right' src='images/sylob.png'/>
    </div>
    <div id='corps'>
<a href="#openModal"><img src="images/video-icon.jpg" height="100" alt="Démonstration"/></a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Video de presentation</h2>
        <video width=97% controls="controls" poster="images/1.jpg">
  <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="loading_div" style="display:none; width: 500px; margin:auto; margin-top: 50px; text-align: center">Veuiller patientez pendant l'execution du script <br /><br /><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
    <div id='tableau1'><table id='table1' border='1'><CAPTION> 229 articles à valoriser </CAPTION>
        <tr>
            <th>Code de l'article
            <th>Désignation
            <th>Nombre de linges de receptions
            <th>Nombre de lignes de commande avec cout d'achat
            <th>Nombre de linges de receptions modifiées
            <th>Article existe dans ABF
            <th>Condition article existe dans ABF
            <th>Autorisation de valorisation
            <th>Etat
        </tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A011606'>0700A011606</a><td>JOINT POUR COUDE VALVE MINISIT<td>2<td>2<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A011607'>0700A011607</a><td>ECROU AVEC OLIVE DIAM. 6<td>2<td>2<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A011700'>0700A011700</a><td>VALVE MINISIT 100° - 340°<td>2<td>2<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A013200'>0700A013200</a><td>VEILLEUSE A 3 VOIES RéF: 0100001<td>2<td>2<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A013300'>0700A013300</a><td>BOUGIE D'ALLUMAGE RéF: 0915036<td>2<td>2<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A014707'>0700A014707</a><td>RACCORD A ANGLE M-M 24x1.5<td>1<td>1<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A019405'>0700A019405</a><td>POIGNEE PORTE FOUR 720 MM<td>2<td>2<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A032601'>0700A032601</a><td>VERRE TREMPE<td>1<td>1<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A041105'>0700A041105</a><td>PIEZO ALLUME GAZ AVEC ECROU DE FIXATION<td>1<td>1<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=08000002'>08000002</a><td>SIPHON POUR VANNE DE VIDANGE BAIN-MARIE<td>1<td>1<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr></table></div><button class='button' id='recalculer'>Revaloriser les articles!</button><br><button class='button' id='maj' style='display:none'>Ok , articles suivants</button><br><div id="tableau2">
</div>
<div id="societe">
<p style='display:none'>Cochise2</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="pied">
<span class='copyright'>Sarl IMB 2015 Tous les droits résérvés</span>
</div>
</html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <Title>Revalorisation des coùts</Title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.json.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#recalculer').on('click', function() {
                var societe=$("#societe p").text();
                var arrayLignes = document.getElementById("table1").rows; //l'array est stocké dans une variable
                var longueur = arrayLignes.length;//on peut donc appliquer la propriété length
                var i=0; //on définit un incrémenteur qui représentera la clé

                while(i<longueur)
                {
                    article = arrayLignes[i].cells[0].textContent;
                    autorisation= arrayLignes[i].cells[7].textContent;
                    if (autorisation=="Oui") {
                        var retour="";
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "sleep.php",
                            async: false,
                            beforeSend: function(){
                                arrayLignes[i].cells[8].innerHTML = "<img height='60' src='images/ajax-loader.gif' />";
                                alert("avant valorisation "+ article);
                            },
                            success: function(msg){
                                    arrayLignes[i].cells[8].innerHTML = "<a href='"+msg+"' target='_blank'><IMG height='60' src='images/ok.png' alt='Voire rapport'></a>";
                                    alert("apres valorisation "+ article);
                                }
                            });
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                    document.getElementById("recalculer").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("maj").style.display = "inline";
                });
            $('#maj').on('click', function() {
                document.location.reload(true);
            });
            });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="entete">
        <img class='left' src='images/logo.png'/>
        <img class='right' src='images/sylob.png'/>
    </div>
    <div id='corps'>
<a href="#openModal"><img src="images/video-icon.jpg" height="100" alt="Démonstration"/></a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Video de presentation</h2>
        <video width=97% controls="controls" poster="images/1.jpg">
  <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="loading_div" style="display:none; width: 500px; margin:auto; margin-top: 50px; text-align: center">Veuiller patientez pendant l'execution du script <br /><br /><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
    <div id='tableau1'><table id='table1' border='1'><CAPTION> 229 articles à valoriser </CAPTION>
        <tr>
            <th>Code de l'article
            <th>Désignation
            <th>Nombre de linges de receptions
            <th>Nombre de lignes de commande avec cout d'achat
            <th>Nombre de linges de receptions modifiées
            <th>Article existe dans ABF
            <th>Condition article existe dans ABF
            <th>Autorisation de valorisation
            <th>Etat
        </tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A011606'>0700A011606</a><td>JOINT POUR COUDE VALVE MINISIT<td>2<td>2<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A011607'>0700A011607</a><td>ECROU AVEC OLIVE DIAM. 6<td>2<td>2<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A011700'>0700A011700</a><td>VALVE MINISIT 100° - 340°<td>2<td>2<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A013200'>0700A013200</a><td>VEILLEUSE A 3 VOIES RéF: 0100001<td>2<td>2<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A013300'>0700A013300</a><td>BOUGIE D'ALLUMAGE RéF: 0915036<td>2<td>2<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A014707'>0700A014707</a><td>RACCORD A ANGLE M-M 24x1.5<td>1<td>1<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A019405'>0700A019405</a><td>POIGNEE PORTE FOUR 720 MM<td>2<td>2<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A032601'>0700A032601</a><td>VERRE TREMPE<td>1<td>1<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=0700A041105'>0700A041105</a><td>PIEZO ALLUME GAZ AVEC ECROU DE FIXATION<td>1<td>1<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr><tr><td><a href='http://serveur-s1/valorisation/page1.php?societe=Cochise2&article=08000002'>08000002</a><td>SIPHON POUR VANNE DE VIDANGE BAIN-MARIE<td>1<td>1<td>0<td>Non<td>Non<td>Oui<td></tr></table></div><button class='button' id='recalculer'>Revaloriser les articles!</button><br><button class='button' id='maj' style='display:none'>Ok , articles suivants</button><br><div id="tableau2">
</div>
<div id="societe">
<p style='display:none'>Cochise2</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="pied">
<span class='copyright'>Sarl IMB 2015 Tous les droits résérvés</span>
</div>
</html>
```